# Specifying targets for makefile command

Tags: makefile

I'm new to makefiles I'm having a bit of trouble distinguishing the target path versus the where the make file exists

Here's my `Makefile`

```
babel-ready:
    make babel-install-preset module=es2015
    make babel-install-preset module=stage-2

babel-install-preset:
    npm install --save-dev babel-preset-$(module)
    ${CURDIR}/node_modules/.bin/json -I -f package.json -e 'if (!this.babel) this.babel = {}' ;\
    ${CURDIR}/node_modules/.bin/json -I -f package.json -e 'if (!this.babel.presets) this.babel.presets = []' ;\
    ${CURDIR}/node_modules/.bin/json -I -f package.json -e 'this.babel.presets.push("'$(module)'")' ;\
```

Here's the dir structure:

```
- node_modules
  - .bin/
    - json
- Makefile
- packages/
  - my-package/
        - package.json
 - package.json
```

I'd like to use this Makefile in three ways.

One is to specify a target like this.

```
./ $ make babel-ready package=my-package
```

Two is to run it on the root package.json.

```
./ $ make babel-ready
```

Third is to be in the package and simply run the command.

```
./packages/my-package $ make -C ../../ babel-ready
```

I'd like it if all three could use the same base code as well.

I keep using `cd` to change the directory within the commands but it keeps messing me up, because once I `cd` I loose access to the make command, and have to use `make -C ${CURDIR}` but then I loose access to the correct `package.json` file, so it seems like I can't get anything to work.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for `make -f ../../Makefile babel-ready` in the last example.  The `-C` option loses the current directory, like you discovered.

(Unclear to me whether your commands correctly use `${CURDIR}`, so you might need additional tweaks.)